# JPA criteria: spatial restrictions

Tags: jpa-2.0, hibernate-criteria, criteria-api, spatial-query, hibernate-spatial

I cannot find any way to use spatial criteria with Hibernate 5.2. Using criteria is not a problem:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<T> cq = cb.createQuery(geoObjectClass);
Root<T> root = cq.from(geoObjectClass);
CriteriaQuery<T> critQuery = cq.select(root);
TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createQuery(critQuery);
```

But how can I add spatial restriction to this? E.g.

```
Criterion sr = SpatialRestrictions.distanceWithin("geometry", location, 0.1);
```

The 'Criterion'-interface is hibernate-specific and I cannot find how to apply it on the 'root' entity above. Is this possible at all?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22689029/1527544

Comment: Thanks, that's quite a useful post. But `session.createCriteria(City.class)` is deprecated. I try not to use those, but apparently there's (still) no other way now?

Comment: since when it is depracated? Besides its you that wanted to use provider specific API.